# CSS: prevent 2 elements from breaking and overlapping

Tags: css, flexbox

i need to make this work in IE10 browser. i think Display flex is not supported by IE10. 
My requirement is .line2 and .line3

```
<div class="line2"></div>
<div class="line3"></div>
```

should be always on the same row. i have tried this using display float. But i'm not able to complete the requirement. The breaking should not happen when screen width is reduced instead a horizontal scroll bar has to be displayed.

below is the pen
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/xdyYYZ)

Comment: `display: -ms-flexbox;` for IE 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[divine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2131576/sankar-raj) mentioned, you can use the tween syntax, `display: -ms-flexbox;`

This article on CSSTricks explains it wee: [Using Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

```
.page-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }
```

And then, to control col width:

```
.main-content {
  width: 60%;
}
.main-nav,
.main-sidebar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  width: 20%;               /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
  -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For IE10 You could try `display: -ms-flexbox;` but in case that doesn't work instead of the `width: 500px;` on `.line2` and `.line3` try using percentages.
in this case give them both a `width: 50%;`. See the code example below:

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
}

.line1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.line2 {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.line3 {
  background-color: violet;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="line1">
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="line2">
    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
  </div>
  <div class="line3">
    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    If you use this site regularly and would like to help keep the site on the Internet, please consider donating a small sum to help pay for the hosting and bandwidth bill. There is no minimum donation, any sum is appreciated - click here to donate using
    PayPal. Thank you for your support.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!